# If $a*b = \sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3}$, how do I show that there exists a bijective mapping from $(\mathbb{R}, *)$ into $(\mathbb{R}, +)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

My attempt was pretty basic:

Suppose $y \in (\mathbb{R}, +)$ such that $\exists x \in (\mathbb{R}, *), \: f(x)=y$. Then $\exists a,b \in  (\mathbb{R}, *)$ such that  $x = a*b$, that is $x = \sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3}$. But from here I don't know what to do. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had such an isomorphism $f : (\mathbb{R}, *) \to (\mathbb{R}, +)$, then it would have to satisfy

$$ f(x * y) = f(x) + f(y) $$

or equivalently

$$ x * y = f^{-1}\left( f(x) + f(y) \right)$$

or instead

$$ x + y = f(f^{-1}(x) * f^{-1}(y)) $$

While there are things one might try in general to try and discover an unknown bijection, the exercise you're given is mainly just a pattern matching exercise: i.e. to match the pattern you're given against small variations on the pattern you need to be true.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

Try with
$$f (x)=x^3$$
and

$$f (a*b)=(a*b)^3$$